# problem with making a member function thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, server

I'm trying to make a function member thread but it give me a run time error:

```
"abort() has been called".
```

here's my code:

```
std::thread th(&Server::accept, this);
```

accept is a member function with no parameters.

here's a git link my error is in Server.cpp line 67

https://gitlab.com/GoldenZ/chat

Comment: is accept a *member* function? because that wouldnt work since you would need an instance of whatever class its from to invoke it

Comment: yes accept is a member function what can I do to fix this problem?

Comment: please create a [MRE]

Comment: @Golden: code like `catch (...) {}` is going to be a source of incredible pain

Comment: @Golden are you sure that `Server::accept` [isn't throwing an exception](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/terminate)?

Comment: someone I know helped me and now it's working

Answer (score 0):

A solution is to wrap the call in a lambda, for example the following code works...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
#include <threads>

struct Server {
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;

    void accept(int x) {
        printf("Inside Server::accept(%i)\n", x);
    }

    void test(int x) {
        threads.push_back(std::thread([x, this](){ accept(x); }));
    }

    ~Server() {
        for (auto& t : threads) {
            t.join();
        }
    }
};

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    Server s;
    s.test(1);
    s.test(2);
    s.test(3);
    s.test(4);
}
```

Comment: I'm creating the thread inside a member function and I need it to have all of the class parameters. so it doesn't work

Comment: @Golden: Please post your [example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-examplehttps://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as part of the question, so we can understand what exactly you're trying to do.

Comment: @Golden: inside `accept` you've all the class members, it's a regular method that will be executed in a separate thread. Of course is your responsibility to ensure that the class instance will not be destroyed during the thread execution and that proper synchronization is used when accessing instance members...

Comment: I added a git link so you can check out my code

Comment: @Golden: I've placed the thread creation in a method

Comment: it works but I need to change it so the function that the thread use will gel a parameter can you show me how to do it?

Comment: @Golden: I've added passing a parameter